# How to translate string as parameter in laravel blade while using include

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to translate a string on my blade that is a parameter being sended on a include:

```
@include('pages.groups.adventureCard', ['title' => 'GREEN WEEKEND','primaryPrice' => '225,00 €'])
```

I know I could just use `@lang($title)` on my `adventureCard.blade.php` but that doesn't allow me to track all my untranslated strings while using a plugin `(kkomelin/laravel-translatable-string-exporter)` that gets what's is in between `@lang('****')` but ignores variables.

I have tried with `trans()`, `@lang()` and `__()` with no success, is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: __() should work, make sure to clear your views and see

Comment: wow thanks, I just had to clear cache and it's working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`__()`](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#method-__) should work

Make sure to clear views cache when you change them if they don't refresh automatically

```
php artisan view:clear
```